# Showing an image title as text with image

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a Wordpress site with images that have titles (put in there at the admin panel )

I want to show those title as text underneath the image but can't find any sources that can do that automatically (through a title tag, javascript etc)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of JavaScript DOM API calls will easily solve this issue:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Get references to the needed DOM elements:
  var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  var parent = images[0].parentNode;

  // Loop through all the images...
  images.forEach(function(image){
    // Create a <span> element
    var span = document.createElement("span");
  
    // Insert the <span> just prior to the current image
    parent.insertBefore(span, image);
  
    // Populate the <span> with the title of the image
    image.previousElementSibling.textContent = image.title;
  });
  
});
```

```css
div > span {
  /* Change the position of the span elements to be below the images */
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0, 105%);
  background:yellow; /* Not needed, just used to show the dynamically created span elements */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="" alt="something1" title="something1">
  <img src="" alt="something2" title="something2">
  <img src="" alt="something3" title="something3">
  <img src="" alt="something4" title="something4">
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like an ad hoc hack in my opinion.

Comment: Good thing everyone is entitled to an opinion. And, you know what they say about opinions, right? There is nothing "ad hoc" or "hack" about this.

Comment: Well, I was trying to be polite. From a technical standpoint, this answer is slower and relies on pulling information programmatically after the page has been loaded. However, it should be noted, that this information is already made readily available to you by the Wordpress API itself. In essence this answer tries to re-invent the wheel on information already exposed to you.

Comment: You sound like you are quite knowledgeable about WordPress, but perhaps not so much about JavaScript and the DOM. This information is just as accessible with the DOM and while there is a performance cost to getting it, you also will pay a performance cost to get it from WordPress. In short, grabbing the title of an element and using it for other purposes using JavaScript is not a "hack", it's called "DOM Scripting" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

Comment: I'm not as advanced as either of you, the site isn't that big, but has a bunch of large sized photos in the content. Just wanted to be able to post the title with the pictures. I'm sure I have performance issues with other parts as well, so not sure how much of an impact that would make

Comment: and in answer to the question, I am not in control of how many images are used and where in the post, and they are full width, as in your example I would like the title to appear below the images

Comment: @user3550879 The 3 lines of JavaScript I showed (along with having a `<span>` element next to each image) solves your problem. It's not complex at all and there really isn't any appreciable performance issue. DrewT's comments are completely misguided.

Comment: Ok cool, can I put the code in the head tag and I can't hardcode a span element as I will not be the one adding images to the post

Comment: @user3550879 I have updated the answer so that you won't have to have any pre-existing `<span>` elements in the HTML. The code dynamically generates them. Put the JavaScript inside of `<script>` and `</script>` elements in the `<head>` and put the CSS inside of `<style>` and `</style>` also in the `<head>`.

Comment: of perfect, I can't add the css to a pre existing css style sheet or does it have to be contained within the page

Comment: You can add it to a Stylesheet, but be warned that depending on the other CSS selectors in use, the ones I'm using may need to be modified to be more specific so that they don't get overridden by other selectors.

Answer (score 0):

To get meta data attributes of images you can use the `wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment_id);` function from the Wordpress API.

Have a look at the documentation here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata

You will see in the return values there is an array of meta data including the image title:

```
    [image_meta] => Array
       (
           [aperture] => 5
           [credit] => 
           [camera] => Canon EOS-1Ds Mark III
           [caption] => 
           [created_timestamp] => 1323190643
           [copyright] => 
           [focal_length] => 35
           [iso] => 800
           [shutter_speed] => 0.016666666666667
           [title] => 
       )
```

Comment: This seems like crazy overkill to get something that is natively available to all image DOM elements.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's the API Wordpress has designed for you to use if you want to use metadata properties of images.

Comment: And the DOM is the API that all web browsers implement and is designed for you to use to get at any metadata of any element.

Comment: I use the simple get_content so it spits out the post and the images. I just wanted to put the image title with the picture, I figured it would be to hard